# Redirect root (but some directories) to subdir w/ Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, nextcloud

I'm using Yunohost to host multiple "apps" on my server that runs Nginx.

Yunohost uses SSOWat to redirect some stuff to the login/apps list page.

I have some apps (NextCloud, RoundCube,…) inside subdirs and a "custom webapp" `my_webapp`.

I would like this :

- `https://mydomain/nextcloud`,etc -> `/webroot/nextcloud/`, etc
- `https://mydomain/` -> `https://mydomain/site` = `/webroot/my_webappp/`
- `https://mydomain/other` -> `https://mydomain/site/other` = `/webroot/my_webappp/other`

Currently the first work but adding

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ /site;
}
```

to the Nginx config seems to redirect some webapps (not all thanks to SSOWat). Especially, the Yunohost user login/apps list is redirected to site/ :(

How can I prevent some subdirs to be redirected but have the other ones redirected to site/ ?